# swapcontext() segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a simple hello world example using swapcontext()

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static ucontext_t uctx_main, uctx_func1;

typedef struct test_struct 
{
    ucontext_t  context;
    int value;
}test_struct;

test_struct* array[10];

static void
func1(void)
{
    printf("func1: started\n");
    printf("func1: TESTING\n");
    printf("func1: returning\n");
}
void init()
{
    memset(array,NULL,10);

    array[0] = (test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    array[0]->value = 10;

    getcontext(&array[0]->context);

    char* func1_stack = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
    //char func1_stack[64];

    array[0]->context.uc_stack.ss_sp = func1_stack;
    array[0]->context.uc_stack.ss_size = 64;
    array[0]->context.uc_link = &uctx_main;

    makecontext(&array[0]->context, func1, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   init();

   printf("VALUE: %d\n",array[0]->value);

   swapcontext(&uctx_main, &array[0]->context);

   printf("VALUE: %d\n",array[0]->value);
   printf("main: exiting\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

But the problem is when the progam executes `swapcontext()` a segmentation fault occurs. I have fiddled around a bit and I figured out that the problem is the stack size that I am assigning to the context but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

P.S. I have tried assigning `sizeof(func1_stack)` but still got a seg fault

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 64 as the stack size as coded is consistent with the actual given stack size.  However, 64 bytes is fairly small for a stack.  The [example here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/makecontext) uses 16K as the stack size.  It may be that the size you are using is simply too small.

As an aside, the `memset` is probably not correct.  It is setting the first 10 bytes of the array.  It is not actually affecting anything, but it should probably be the following:

```
memset(array,0,sizeof(array)));
```